# Haskel how can I turn this list of string into a list of lists?

Tags: string, haskell

The string looks like this:

```
",w84,w41,w56,w170,w56,w41,w84,/,,w24,w40,w17,w40,w48,,/ ,,,w16,w16,w16,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,b1,b1,b1,,,/ ,,b3,b130,b17,b130,b129,,/,b69,b146,b131,b170,b131,b146,b69,"
```

But it should look like this

```
[[Empty,Piece White 84,Piece White 41,Piece White 56,Piece White 170,Piece White 56,Piece White 41,Piece White 84,Empty],[Empty,Empty,Piece White 24,Piece White 40,Piece White 17,Piece White 40,Piece White 48,Empty,Empty],[Empty,Empty,Empty,Piece White 16,Piece White 16,Piece White 16,Empty,Empty,Empty],[Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty],[Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty],[Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty],[Empty,Empty,Empty,Piece Black 1,Piece Black 1,Piece Black 1,Empty,Empty,Empty],[Empty,Empty,Piece Black 3,Piece Black 130,Piece Black 17,Piece Black 130,Piece Black 129,Empty,Empty],[Empty,Piece Black 69,Piece Black 146,Piece Black 131,Piece Black 170,Piece Black 131,Piece Black 146,Piece Black 69,Empty]]
```

The list my code creates looks like this:

> [["Empty,Piece White 84,Piece White 41,Piece White 56,Piece White 170,Piece White 56,Piece White 41,Piece White 84,Empty"],
> ["Empty,Empty,Piece White 24,Piece White 40,Piece White 17,Piece White 40,Piece White 48,Empty,Empty"],
> ["Empty,Empty,Empty,Piece White 16,Piece White 16,Piece White 16,Empty,Empty,Empty"],
> ["Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty"]

```
data Player = Black | White deriving Show
data Cell = Piece Player Int | Empty deriving Show
data Pos = Pos { col :: Char, row :: Int } deriving Show
type Board = [[Cell]]
```

I have these data types.

I am almost done with this task all I need is to get rid of the quotation marks.

This is my code so far:

```
buildBoard x =  rec(help3(wop(helper (replaceO x))))


wop (x:xs) = splitOn "/" (x:xs)

help3 (x:xs) = map (\x -> [x])(x:xs)

rec (x:xs) = map(\x -> [recH(x)])(x:xs)

recH (x:xs) = checkComma(x)

helper (x:y:xs) 
            |x == ',' && y == ',' = x:'E':'m':'p':'t':'y':helper(y:xs)
            |otherwise = x:helper (y:xs)
helper [] = []
helper [x] = [x]

checkComma (x:xs) = if head (x:xs) == ',' then checkComma('E':'m':'p':'t':'y':',':xs) else if last (x:xs) == ',' then reverse(turnAr(reverse(x:xs))) else (x:xs)

turnAr (x:xs) = 'y':'t':'p':'m':'E':',':xs

replaceO [] = []
replaceO (x:xs) = 
     if x == 'w' 
      then 'P':'i':'e':'c':'e':' ':'W':'h':'i':'t':'e':' ': replaceO xs 
     else if x == 'b'
      then 'P':'i':'e':'c':'e':' ':'B':'l':'a':'c':'k':' ': replaceO xs
     else if x == 'E'
      then 'E':'m':'p':'t':'y':' ': replaceO xs
     else x : replaceO xs
```

Comment: while there is a way you can do it using the `Read` type class, the more relevant question here is: how are you getting that string representation? Because you can probably change that code to not convert them to strings in the first place. (The only exception being if that comes from string input like user input or a file etc.)

Comment: Yeah I could change my code the way the task is suppose to be done is in the following: You get a fen string(",w84,w41,w56,w170,w56,w41,w84,/,,w24,w40,w17,w40,w48,,/ ,,,w16,w16,w16,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,b1,b1,b1,,,/ ,,b3,b130,b17,b130,b129,,/,b69,b146,b131,b170,b131,b146,b69,") this string should be turned into a Board. Every comma at the beginning is a empty space and every ,, is an empty space. My solution now just needs to get rid of the quotations.

Comment: I will post the code I have under my question!

Comment: OK so how are you transforming that to the reresentation youo've shown us in the question? I think this is information that should be included in the question. You must have some moderately complex function(s) that parse those strings into the strings you've got - it should be straightforward to change those so they return a `Cell` directly instead of the string representation.

Answer (score 1):

Just getting rid of the quotation marks is not something you can easily do.

I think you'll have to make some significant changes to your code. I'd recommend doing the `splitOn "/"` first and then further `splitOn ","` which yields a list of lists of strings where each of the strings represents a cell.

Then you can pretty easily write a function `parseCell :: String -> Cell` to parse those inner cells. This function will be a bit like your `replaceO` function but it should also handle all empty cells and actually parsing the integers (you can use the `read` function for that).

Comment: Yeah it worked out good I tested a little more and overwrote most of my code. Now I'm only stuck with this question: How can I filter integers from a  string?
numbers xs = filter (\x-> x `elem` ['0'..'9']) xs
This functions returns all the ints from a String. But what if I want the first numbers of a string? Example "12w15" I now only want the function to filter the first x Ints of the string. How can I do that do you maby have an idea?